# How can I get rid of that white space at the bottom between the container and the child elements

Tags: html, css, whitespace

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child one"> <p>This is box one</p> </div
      ><div class="child two">
        <p>This is box two</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The CSS code

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.parent {
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.child {
  border: 5px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
```

I tried every thing from setting margins of the two child elements to 0, the padding of the parent element to 0....nothing seems to work please check the given photo[this photo shows what I get from this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZshUb.png)

Comment: setting the margin to 0 for the p element didn't do the trick as well :(

Answer (score 1):

The `margin` is coming from the `<p>` elements.

Try using the DevTools on your browser of choice. Inspect the elements in the block you suspect is giving you the issue, that way you can self-diagnose.

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, then you need to set the property for `.child`

```
.child {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: This created a white space also to the top and the bottom.....but when I zoom in this problem disappears why is that?

Comment: browser render. try different vertical-align. better use display: flex

Comment: @ЮрийКопоть OP's issue is not an alignment issue, but a margin issue. The `<p>` elements have margin, not their containing parent elements, hence the whitespace.

Comment: @frankied the internal margin (p) in this case does NOT affect the external spaces. Otherwise the outer spaces were the same as the margin(s)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this white line is a problem in the rendering in your browser. I just tried it in JSFiddle using a Brave Browser and a Safari.

In Brave (similar to Chrome), when I change the zoom on the page the white line appears or disappears, depending on how much zoom. When I tried it in Safari, this did not happen, the white line never appeared between the elements.

I would say for you to try doing this test in different browsers because the styles seem to not be responsible for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When You do CSS reset, set margin and padding to 0 for all properties

```
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

And then if the problem still occurs, inspect elements on your browser.